# Setting nested object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, properties

How would I add a "property" to an object? I tried: `players[data.id].name = data.name;`
but it's not working.
Edit: this worked, thanks for the help guys!:

```
players[data.id] = {name: "Johnny"};
```

What I want to achieve: (data.id is already defined)

```
var players = {};
players[data.id].name = "Johnny";
players[data.id].age = 13;
console.log(players[data.id].name]);  ---> Johnny
```

Comment: If your `players` object associates a key to a `Player` object, you can easily do it

Comment: You need to store an empty object on `players[data.id]` before adding properties to it, like: `var players = {}; players[data.id] = {}; players[data.id].name = "Johnny"; players[data.id].age = 13;`. Or maybe you can write: `var players = {}; players[data.id] = {name: "Johnny", age: 13};`

Answer (score 1):

welcome to stackoverflow ! You need to define what `players[data.id]` is first.
Then you can assign data to it. In your example, you are only logging the `name` property of your object, remove the `.name` to show the whole object.

```js
let data = { id: "test" };
var players = {};
players[data.id] = {}
players[data.id].name = "Johnny";
players[data.id].age = 13;
console.log(players[data.id]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention players[data.id] is already defined. Sorry.

Comment: @part1cle the same principle still applies, you are only logging the name property of your object.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to declare 'players[data.id]' as an object. 
The flow of the code would be like

```
    var players = {};
    players["dataId"] = {};
    players["dataId"].name = "Johnny";
    players["dataId"].age = 13;
    console.log(players["dataId"].name);
```

Comment: Looks like you included narrative answer text in your code chunk. Just delete the spaces in front of those lines to change that.